# Proof rules for quantifiers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, quantifiers

Suppose my premise is "for all x: P(x)" and I am trying to prove "exists y: Q(y)".
Which quantifier proof rule could I use in the first step of my proof, and which in the last?

My answer to this would be rule of specification, then existence. However, I am stuck on the difference between instantiation proof and existence. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: There is no general implication like $(\forall x : P(x)) \implies (\exists y: Q(y))$. It depends on the specific content of $P$ and $Q$.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prove it because it is not *valid*.

Consider the interpretation with domain the set $\mathbb N$ of *natural* numbers and interpret $P(x)$ as $x \ge 0$ and $Q(y)$ as $y < 0$.

Under this interpretation, the formula means :

> $\forall x (x \ge 0) \to \exists y (y < 0)$.

In $\mathbb N$ the *antecedent* is *true* while the *consequent* is *false*: thus, the formula is *false*.